# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int when using confluent_kafka Avro deserializer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, fastavro

I'm encountering an OverflowError when attempting to deserialize messages using the **confluent_kafka **Avro deserializer in Python. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class ConsumerKafka:
    def __init__(self, deserializer):
        self.deserializer = deserializer
        self.consumer = Consumer()

    def decode(self, msg_value):      
            deserialized_data = self.deserializer(msg_value, None)
```

I want to underline that sel. serilizer is AvroDeserializer object from onfluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro

when i call the self.deserializer(msg_value, None)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\048115571\Documents\python\TTA\read_from_topic\modules\consumer.py", line 30, in decode
    deserialized_data = self.deserializer(msg_value, None)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\048115571\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\confluent_kafka\schema_registry\avro.py", line 429, in __call__
    obj_dict = schemaless_reader(payload,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 1142, in fastavro._read.schemaless_reader
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 1169, in fastavro._read.schemaless_reader
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 748, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 621, in fastavro._read.read_record
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 740, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 558, in fastavro._read.read_union
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 724, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 393, in fastavro._read.read_array
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 748, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 621, in fastavro._read.read_record
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 740, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 558, in fastavro._read.read_union
  File "fastavro\\_read.pyx", line 770, in fastavro._read._read_data
  File "fastavro\\_logical_readers.pyx", line 22, in fastavro._logical_readers.read_timestamp_millis
  File "fastavro\\_logical_readers.pyx", line 24, in fastavro._logical_readers.read_timestamp_millis
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
```

I try to update all libraries but I can't sorting out. Could someone please provide insights into what might be causing this error and how to address it? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that in C language, int types are fixed size, commonly 16, 32 or 64 bits, less frequently up to 128 bits. On the other hand, Python uses dynamic sized integers, what is sometimes called multi-precision arithmetics. So it is absolutely possible to have a very large integer in Python that cannot be represented with any integer C type. Not a solution but only an explaination, hence a mere comment...

Comment: I will try to debug the avro.py lib. In  opinion this ia a confluent_kafka bug